# Unable to use JConsole with Tomcat running as windows service

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, jconsole

I am running tomcat 6.0.18 as a windows service. In the service applet the jvm is configured default, i.e. it is using jvm.dll of the JRE.

I am trying to monitor this application with JConsole but cannot connect to it locally. I added the parameter -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote (which works when starting tomcat with the start.bat script). But the jvm does not seem to pick up the parameter.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a nice GUI to edit the options, no need to muck around in the registry.

Open up the C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin\tomcat6.exe (or just double-click on the monitor icon in the task bar). Go to the Java pane, add the following to the list of arguments, and restart Tomcat.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Then you can connect with JConsole or the newer VisualVM.

Comment: With this config I am able to connect to the process as a remote process on `localhost:8086` (no need to enter username and password)

Comment: Just a note: `tomcat6.exe` configuration panel is now called `Tomcat7w.exe`

Answer (score 3):

Here's the prescribed way for changing jvmoptions & interacting with the service:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html

I would try going into your registry at HKLM/Software/Apache Software Foundation/Procrun 2.0//Parameters/Java and editing the "Options" multi-string value directly.

Comment: If on 64bit, HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\<name>\Java

Answer (score 3):

There is still a rather simple way to connect JConsole to Java process started as Windows Service using the local mode which I discovered [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/monitoring_java_processes_running_as).

Basically it says that in order to connect to Java process launched as a Windows Service you need to launch JConsole as a Windows Service (you can do it using windows native api or using any wrapper like [yajsw](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/).)

By the way, this will free you from restarting the Java Process which was critical for me.

Answer (score 2):

If Tomcat is running as a Windows service, and you want to attach to the JVM locally, you need to run VisualVM or JConsole as the System account.  You can use [Sysinternals PsExec.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to accomplish this.

```
psexec.exe -i -s c:\visualvm\bin\visualvm.exe
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. D:\Packages\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>psexec -i -s jvisualvm.exe

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


jvisualvm.exe exited on MACHINENAME01 with error code -1073741819.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting it mainly to record this information to myself, I haven't validated it - but this is supposed to work as well:

http://mysqlandsqlserver.blogspot.com/2010/02/jconsolejmap-and-tomcat-as-windows.html

Comment: This worked for me on 64 bit Windows laptop.  Extra point for not requiring any extra software to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following near the top of your catalina.bat

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote ^
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086 ^
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false ^
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Stop and restart tomcat (obviously)

Run jconsole.exe. If your tomcat is running as service, then run jconsole.exe as administrator.

Select Remote Process and enter localhost:8086

Comment: I added these parameters in setEnv file in tomcat7 directory, it works like a charm.