# How do you run jvisualvm.exe under the local system account under Windows Server 2008?

Tags: java, windows-services, windows-server-2008, psexec, jvisualvm

I've been looking for a comparable approach as posted [here for Windows Server 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100446/how-do-you-run-jvisualvm-exe-under-the-local-system-account-under-windows-server) for starting jvisualvm under system account. But I got the error:

> `...\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\jvisualvm.exe exited on ... with error code -1073741819.`

I found that jvisualvm is using a configuration file:

> `...\jdk1.6.0_24\lib\visualvm\etc\visualvm.conf`

This configuration file contains a `default_userdir` property that points to `${HOME}/...`. The system account seems to have issues with `${HOME}`. Changing this parameter and replace `${HOME}` with `C:/Temp` makes the above mentioned solution available for Windows Server 2008 R2 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has the answer in it, but I wanted to summarize the steps.

Note that for me jvisualvm was not printing or logging anything when it failed to start up.  I just had to make sure I updated that conf file correctly.

So just follow the steps from:
[How do you run jvisualvm.exe under the local system account under Windows Server 2003?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100446/how-do-you-run-jvisualvm-exe-under-the-local-system-account-under-windows-server)

and then use this conf tip.
I was now able to see the processes, but I still cannot capture detailed JVM info like thread dumps.