# Why is there no local MBeanServer if Tomcat runs as a Windows service?

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

If Tomcat runs as a Windows service (created using the Windows Tomcat installer) you can't simply enable JMX using `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote`. You also need to set `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<port>`. This is, among other places, explained here: [Unable to use JConsole with Tomcat running as windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503057/unable-to-use-jconsole-with-tomcat-running-as-windows-service)

However, I haven't found an explanation anywhere WHY this is the way it is.

Comment: Is this true for all users, including those in the local system administrators group?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Answer: yes, sort of. I'll answer my own question as I've learned a few things digging through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a bit lost and confused when I wrote the question. Here's what I've learned in the meantime. Usually the Tomcat Windows service runs under the local system account. That's the main reason for all the fuss.

If you simply set `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` in the service config's JVM settings JMX *will* be enabled indeed. If you have a JMX client that runs in the same JVM instance (e.g. because it's baked into the application itself) you can get a hold of the `MBeanServer` like so: `MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(<specific-agent-ID-or-null>)`. However, JConsole won't list this Tomcat process. It's all explained here: https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/monitoring_java_processes_running_as.

As explained elsewhere, if this is not good enough you also need to set `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<port>`. Then you can connect to JMX with JConsole using `localhost:<port>`. From Java code this can be achieved using:

```
JMXServiceURL target = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:<port>/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(target);
connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
```